# Salto de linea en R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Estoy confeccionando un informe tal que...

````
---
title: "Analisis General de la situación"
author: "Roberto Quintela"
date: "21/5/2020"
output: 
html_document:
 theme: cerulean
 toc: yes
 toc_depth: 2
---
****
# Producción

## Evolución histórica

Análizamos en primer lugar la Producción de FULCRUm desde el año 2000 hasta hoy en día en TODOS los 
proyectos facturables incluyendo aquellos que ya están cerrados

Esto nos da un total de `r nrow(dfInforme)` Proyectos analizados con la siguiente distribución anual

```{r echo=FALSE}
Genero un grafico
```
## En el 2020

Este año tenemos...
````

Pero el ultimo en cabezado me sale a la derecha del grafico en vez de debajo
[image: informe]

y no se donde puede estar el problema

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El problema se resuelve dejando una linea más entre el final del chunck y el encabezado

````
```

## En el 2020
````

Este año tenemos...

Comment: Por favor, visita el apartado de SO sobre lo que se considera un buena respuesta. Comaprto el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . De no modificarla puede ser eliminada. Gracias